# Logic for selecting best nearby venues for display on a map

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, geolocation, logic

I have an app that displays information about certain venues. Each venue is awarded a rating on a scale from 0-100. The app includes a map, and on the map I'd like to show the best nearby venues. (The point is to recommend to the user alternative venues that they might like.)

What is the best way to approach this problem?

- If I fetch the nearest *x* venues, many bad venues (i.e. those with a
  low rating) show.
- If I fetch the highest rated venues, many of them
  will be too far away to be useful as recommendations.

This seems like a pretty common challenge for any geolocation app, so I'm interested to know what approach other people have taken.

- I have considered "scoring" each possible venue by taking into account its rating and its distance in miles.
- I've also considered fetching the highest rated venues within a *y* mile radius, but this gets problematic because in some cities there are a lot of venues in a small area (e.g. New York) and in others it's reasonable to recommend venues that are farther away.

(This is a Rails app, and I'm using Solr with the Sunspot gem to retrieve the data. But I'm not necessarily looking for answers in code here, more just advice about the logic.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would implement a few formulas and use some form of [A/B testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing) to get an idea as to which ones yield the best results on some outcome metric. What exactly that metric is is up to you. It could be clicks, or it could be something more complicated.

Start out with the simplest formula you can think of (ideally one that is computationally cheap as well) to establish a baseline. From there, you can iterate, but the absolute key concept is that you'll have hard data to tell you if you're getting better or worse, not just a hunch (perhaps that a more complicated formula is better). Even if you got your hands on Yelp's formula, it might not work for you.

For instance, as you mentioned, a single score calculated based on some linear combination of inverse distance and establishment quality would be a good starting point and you can roll it out in a few minutes. Make sure to normalize each component score in some way. Here's a possible very simple algorithm you could start with:

1. Filter venues as much as possible on fast-to-query attributes (by type, country, etc.)
2. Filter remaining venues within a fairly wide radius (you'll need to do some research into exactly how to do this in a performant way; there are plenty of posts on Stackoverflow and else where on this. You'll want to index your database table on latitude and longitude, and follow a number of other best practices).
3. Score the remaining venues using some weights that seem intuitive to you (I arbitrarily picked 0.25 and 0.75, but they should add up to 1:

> score = 0.25*(1-((distance/distance of furthest venue in remaining
>   set)-distance of closest venue)) + 0.75*(quality score/highest quality
>   score in remaining set)

4. Sort them by score and take the top *n*

I would put money on Yelp using some fancy-pants version of this simple idea. They may be using machine learning to actually select the weights for each component score, but the conceptual basis is similar.

While there are plenty of possibilities for calculating formulas of varying complexity, the only way to truly know which one works best is to gather data.

Answer (score 0):

I would fix the number of venues returned at say 7.

Discard all venues with scores in the lowest quartile of reviewers scores, to avoid bad customer experiences, then return the top 7 within a postcode. If this results in less than 7 entries, then look to the neighboring post codes to find the best scores to complete the list.

This would result in a list of top to mediocre scores locally, perhaps with some really good scores only a short distance away.

From a UX perspective this would easily allow users to either select a postcode/area they are interested in or allow the app to determine its location.

From a data perspective, you already have addresses. The only "tricky" bit is determining what the neighboring postcodes/areas are, but I'm sure someone has figured that out already.

As an aside, I'm a great believer in things changing. Like restaurants changing hands or the owners waking up and getting better. I would consider offering a "dangerous" list of sub-standard eateries "at your own risk" as another form of evening entertainment. Personally I have found some of my worst dining experiences have formed some of my best dining out stories :-) And if the place has been harshly judged in the past you can sometimes find it is now a gem in the making.

Answer (score 0):

First I suggest that you use bayesian average to maintain an overall rating for all the venues, more info here: https://github.com/tyrauber/acts_rateable

Then you can retrieve the nearest venues ordered by distance then ordered by rating. two order by statements in your query